# images to video using CV2

Tags: python, opencv

i am trying to create a video from a folder of images , the script run without error , but I receive a video of 6kb , I marked a print to see if the script read all the pictures in the folder all it's ok , but I still don't have a result
this is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

frameSize = (500, 500)

out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_video.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 2, frameSize)

for filename in glob.glob('thumbnails/*.jpg'):
    print(filename)
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    out.write(img)

out.release()
```

Comment: are those pictures actually *that size*? what does `out.isOpened()` say?

Comment: like @ChristophRackwitz asked, you will get a 6kb file if the pictures are not exactly the same size as frameSize. you will have to manually resize the images to frameSize before out.write(img)